# System.ArgumentException: 'No se puede enlazar la propiedad o la columna IDADM en DataSource. Arg_ParamName_Name'

Tags: c#, forms

I've been having this problem with my code, which is a form application to manage a company's customer database, but I don't know what could lead to this error or if I have to redo the database because before I didn't get this error and it worked perfectly

```
private int clienteId;
public DetallesCliente(int id)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    clienteId = id;
    conectClass conectClass = new conectClass();
    Contactos contacto = conectClass.selectContactosById(clienteId);
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            // Obtén el nombre del TextBox
            string textBoxName = control.Name;

            // Busca una propiedad con el mismo nombre en el objeto certificado
            PropertyInfo property = contacto.GetType().GetProperty(textBoxName);

            if (property != null)
            {
                // Configura el data binding
                ((TextBox)control).DataBindings.Add("Text", property, textBoxName, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null, "D");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the client class has this structure

```
public Contactos(int id, string organizacion, string apellidos, string nombre, string correo, string cargo, string fijo1, string movil, string movil2, string direccion, string ciudad, string provincia, int cP, string web, string notas, string facturas, string certificados, string planos, string contratos, string frecuancia, string servicio, string iVA, string nombreFacturacion, string datosFiscales, string direccionFacturacion, int cPFacturacion, int importeServicio, int importeChoque, string importeContrato, string tipoCuenta, string formaPago, string provinciaFacturacion, string ciudadFacturacion, int iDADM, string organizacionADM, string zonas, string zonas2, string zonas3, string zonas4, string descripcionFactura)
{
    Id = id;
    Organizacion = organizacion;
    Apellidos = apellidos;
    Nombre = nombre;
    Correo = correo;
    Cargo = cargo;
    Fijo1 = fijo1;
    Movil = movil;
    Movil2 = movil2;
    Direccion = direccion;
    Ciudad = ciudad;
    Provincia = provincia;
    CP = cP;
    Web = web;
    Notas = notas;
    Facturas = facturas;
    Certificados = certificados;
    Planos = planos;
    Contratos = contratos;
    Frecuencia = frecuancia;
    Servicio = servicio;
    IVA = iVA;
    NombreFacturacion = nombreFacturacion;
    DatosFiscales = datosFiscales;
    DireccionFacturacion = direccionFacturacion;
    CPFacturacion = cPFacturacion;
    ImporteServicio = importeServicio;
    ImporteChoque = importeChoque;
    ImporteContrato = importeContrato;
    TipoCuenta = tipoCuenta;
    FormaPago = formaPago;
    ProvinciaFacturacion = provinciaFacturacion;
    CiudadFacturacion = ciudadFacturacion;
    IDADM = iDADM;
    OrganizacionADM = organizacionADM;
    Zonas = zonas;
    Zonas2 = zonas2;
    Zonas3 = zonas3;
    Zonas4 = zonas4;
    DescripcionFactura = descripcionFactura;
}
```

Review the full Stack Trace
Null Handling
Check all properties
Try one property at a time